# Windows Service disappears from services.msc list when stopped, c++

Tags: c++, windows-services

I have an issue with a windows service that I am writing in c++ on Windows 7. The service works fine, when I "install" it and is removed when I "uninstall" (from services.msc list), but I am having 2 issues which I was hoping I could get some help with

1. If I stop the service (via services.msc), the service disappears from services.msc list.
2. If I stop the service via my program, the startup type of the service changes to disabled and hence does not have the "Start/Stop/Restart" buttons.

The service is stopped successfully.

I was hoping for a pointer in the right direction, I am using MSDN as the guide to writing the service. The service when started works fine.

Thank You

Comment: Ok. I'll edit my post and add the code. Any specific section or should I post the entire thing ?

Comment: The code you have written for service startup and shutdown.